# Pass a variable from a PHP script to WordPress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pass a variable from a PHP script I've written to a function in WordPress functions.php.

The code is being called all the time and the variable is not being passed.

Any idea what and doing wrong?

```
$mycountry="GB";
my_function($mycountry);
// functions.php code
add_action( 'wc_price_based_country_before_frontend_init', 'my_function' );
function my_function($mycountry) {
   wcpbc_set_woocommerce_country("$mycountry");
}
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? If yes: what?

Comment: It just doesn't work, no errors so it looks like the variable is not passed to the function to make it work or the code in the php file is not triggering the function in functions.php. I'm probably doing something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define your variable in your function with the `global` keyword to access the variable that was defined in the global scope.

```
global $mycountry="GB";
```

Also, I think there should not be any doublequotes when sending `$mycountry` as a parameter to `wcpbc_set_woocommerce_country()`

```
add_action( 'wc_price_based_country_before_frontend_init', 'my_function' );
function my_function() {
   global $mycountry;
   wcpbc_set_woocommerce_country($mycountry);
}
```

Comment: Tried that but no joy.

I think the code needs to be something along the lines of do_action('my_function', '$mycountry');

Which i tried but didn't work

Comment: I think there should not be quotes here around $mycountry --> wcpbc_set_woocommerce_country("$mycountry");

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work.  The parameter is not being passed from my php file to the function which is in functions.php.

Comment: Sorry @Mick, I edited my answer now. Could you try again with my new edited version?

Comment: Thanks but no luck, the code to switch countries works fine but the parameter from my function is not being passed to it. So if I make it an unconditional statement it works but if its activated by the parameter it doesn't

Comment: What happens is that; when Wordpress calls wc_price_based_country_before_frontend_init action, your callback function my_function is hooked and executed.

Comment: What you can do is to write a new function that returns the mycountry variable and you can call it inside the my_function before wcpbc_set_woocommerce_country()

Comment: Thanks but the currency is set based on a form submission so I cannot see a way for it to be called by functions.php

Comment: You can get the current currency in your custom function with $currency = get_woocommerce_currency(); and then change the country based on that data.